# Any MYSQL Client with fully dark theme?

Tags: mysql, client

I would like to find a MYSQL Client program which can be config as FULLY
DARK THEME. Many of them can not be dark theme in displaying result in grid.

Comment: The MySQL Workbench theme is nice? Just for kicks, why do you want thjis? The MySQL CLI client using a terminal window might get a retro effect - green screen/Star Trek (early series).

Comment: in MySQL Workbench, I can adjust the editor's color in code_editor.xml but the grid window is keep in white background .  which is only can be set by MS Windows. My eye are suffer from it.   (T_T)

Comment: Sympathies, but skins/themes on clients are not a big priority here :-(. All I can suggest is to download a number of them and trybthem to see if they'll do what you want! Can you turn down the brightness on your physical screen?

Comment: Try **[visql](https://github.com/paulfitz/visql)** ;)

Comment: DBeaver is my favorite client tool and it has a dark theme.

Answer (score 4):

HeidiSQL has some nice dark themes.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

DBForge Studio has exactly what you are looking for.

Once installed, go to Tools -> Skin -> Visual Studio 2013 Dark. Everything will be dark (The database tree view, the query windows, the table results, etc).